# will unity 3d on older computers work with 13.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, nvidia, unity-2d, 3d

Basically, i have an older computer which is why i put ubuntu on for its speed. At first i had 12.04 that ran ubuntu 2D because 3D was very slow on the Nvidia GeForce 5200 card in it. when i updated to 12.10 unity 2D was discontinued and because it was forcing my computer to run Unity 3D the desktop kept crashing leaving me to use Gnome desktop.

ive seen that 13.10 has improvements and what not, but if i update to it, will the 3D for me still crash or was it optimized for better performance? if it isnt, then i wont bother updating from 12.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an try for 13.10, if it works, fine.If it doesn't, you may stick to 12.10 for some time.**Ubuntu Gnome** is an continuation of the old look that people love.You may want to try it.You can always go with **xubuntu** or **lubuntu** or **kubuntu** which are better for low spec hardware.

BTW you will not be able(or recommended) to stick with 12.10 much longer as it EOL's in Apr 2014(that's also the time when 14.04 LTS will be launched).

So in short, you have following options.

- **Stick with Ubuntu 12.10** and jump to Ubuntu 14.04 quickly via 13.10.See if it(14.04) works.
- **Try out Ubuntu 13.10**, See if it works.
- Get yourself transfered to **Gnome** or **others**.

> We don't have not yet evolved forecasting powers.You will only have to try 13.10 to check if it works the way you want.Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thanks for the opinion, sice I've been using the gnome desktop and 12.10 is going out ill just update and see what happens.